# This Oracle SQL doesn't work in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

```
if :p6_internal_id is null then 

INSERT INTO  table 
 (

   id,
   account  
  )

values
  (

    tseq_id.nextval,
   :p6_account,


  );

    else

  update table set "all columns"  where id = :p6_internal_id;

  end if ;
```

This says

> ORA-00927: missing equal sign

for the `update set "all columns"` line.

I don't know how to fix this. How do I set the value of all the columns where id is what I enter?

Comment: `set` needs a column to assign a value to and a value.

Comment: Thank you for editing it  @Álvaro González . So do I need to list out each column and set it individually ? For instance

Comment: Which (columns) in the table are you trying to update, and where will the new value(s) come from? Do you have a column called `"all columns"` as a quoted identifier, or is that supposed to represent some pseudo-set of columns?

Comment: I have 2 columns here so update table set  id=  :p6_internal_id ,set account= :p6_acct ?

Comment: I mean all columns in my table by "All columns"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, you just need to change that line to:

```
update table set account = :p6_account where id = :p6_internal_id;
```

You don't need to set the `id` column to `:p6_internal_id` as you know it already has that value - since you're using it in the `where` clause.

There is no magic value of '"all columns"' that would allow every column to be updated at once, not least because you need to supply a value that corresponds to every column anyway, and in the right order.

If you have multiple columns to set then you have to list them all explicitly, with each column/value pair separated by commas; e.g. with a few made-up columns and bind variables:

```
update table set account = :p6_account,
  name = :p6_name,
  amount := p6_amount
where id = :p6_internal_id;
```

You can see the required syntax [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5).

Comment: So I have 50 columns . Do i need to update them all like that ?

Comment: Yes, because otherwise how will it know what value to use for each of the 50 columns? You only need to set those that might have changed though. If your Apex application only lets the user enter the `id` and `account` then there can't be changes to other columns anyway (unless you have, say, a last-updated column you want to set to the current time, which you might be doing via a trigger anyway).

Comment: This Sql is like the insert SQL for a table where I am able to access all the records by clicking on the id number of a row . I created a Sequence so that everytime I edit it it is saved with a new id number . Howeever I dont want that , so I am trying to update the same unique record with the if statement such that if id (:p6_internal _id)is null  then insert all the values from the page items  into the table else update the table set "all columns" with the page items where id =:p6_internal_id .

Comment: OK, then you do need to list all the columns and their new values - you have to tell it that `account` comes from `:p6_account` and so on for all those columns..Otherwise it has no way of knowing. (*You* know you can just stick a `:p6_` prefix on everything; Oracle does not.) There are ways of diagrammatically generating the statements if you just don't want to type them all out. The same applies to the insert, which presumably needs to include all 50 columns (and matching values) too. (I would have thought Apex would have a simpler way to let you edit a table, but I don't use it...)